# jQuery Deferred, trouble getting a value in a chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

The result of buildMyUrl is always undefined in the calling function.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong chaining these functions:

```
var buildMyUrl = function (callback)
{   
    var param;

    var addParams = function (domainUrl)
    {
        domainUrl += "page.aspx?";
        domainUrl += "Param1=";
    };

    $.when(self.buildDomainUrl()).then(addParams);
};
```

`buildDomainUrl` returns a JQuery promise and adding parameters works fine.
Now I have a function that would like to use the result of `buildMyUrl`:

```
    var buildAPageUrl  = function ()
    {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        var addCalendarPage = function (domainUrl)
        {
             dfd.resolve(domainUrl += "/Calendar.aspx?");
        };

   // Here lies the problem (buildMyUrl is undefined)
        $.when(buildMyUrl()).then(addCalendarPage);

        return dfd.promise();
    }
```

Comment: Where is `buildMyLoginUrl()` defined?

Comment: @Kevin B.  buildMyLoginUrl should just be buildMyUrl my mistake.

Comment: `buildMyURL` isn't returning a deferred object. It isn't returning anything.

Comment: Thats my question, I have tried to get buildMyUrl to return a promise but I can't get it to work.  I don't know what I do wrong

Comment: Your function literally isn't returning anything. try `return $.when(...).then(...);`. You have to instruct to it what should be returned.

Comment: putting the return in front returns the when but not the then

Comment: the `then` isn't a deferred object. `then` is a method similar to `done` and `fail` that adds callbacks to a deferred object. `$.when` does infact return a deferred object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works based on Kevin B's comments:

```
var buildMyUrl = function (callback)
{   
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var param;

    var addParams = function (domainUrl)
    {
        domainUrl += "page.aspx?";
        domainUrl += "Param1=";
        dfd.resolve();
    };

    $.when(self.buildDomainUrl()).then(addParams);
    return dfd.promise();
};
```